# JUnit testing failing with constructors

Tags: javascript, junit

Hi there I am having trouble trying to JUNIT test my Constructors with invalid args. Everything else in my test works but when I try to execute the test case with  the invalid constructors values I am getting following error:

"Expected IllegalArgumentException to be thrown but nothing was thrown".

here is my code.

```
package song;
public abstract class song {

    private String name;
    private String genre;
    private double length;
    private int chartNumber;
    
    /**
     * Setting the limit values 
     * 
     */
    public final static int NAME_LOWER_LIMIT = 1;
    public final static int CHART_LOWER_LIMIT = 1;
    public final static int CHART_UPPER_LIMIT = 10;
    public final static int GENRE_LENGTH = 1;
    public final static double LENGTH_LOWER_LIMIT = 1.00;
    public final static double LENGTH_UPPER_LIMIT = 5.00;
    

    public song() {
    
    }
    
    

    public song(String name, String genre, double length, int chartNumber) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.length = length;
        this.chartNumber = chartNumber;
    }



    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     * Name must have at least one character
     */
    public void setName(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        if(name.length()>=NAME_LOWER_LIMIT) {
        this.name = name;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name value too short");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the genre
     */
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    /**
     * @param genre the genre to set
     * Genre must be at least one charter
     */
    public void setGenre(String genre) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if(genre.length()>=GENRE_LENGTH) {
            this.genre = genre;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Genre name too short");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the length
     */
    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    /**
     * @param length the length to set
     * Length has to be greater than 1.00 and less than 5.00
     */
    public void setLength(double length) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if((length >= LENGTH_LOWER_LIMIT) && (length <= LENGTH_UPPER_LIMIT)) {
            this.length = length;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("song length not inside the boundries");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the chartNumber
     * Chart limit has to be between 1 -20
     */
    public int getChartNumber() {
        return chartNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param chartNumber the chartNumber to set
     * Chart number must be between 1 -10
     */
    public void setChartNumber(int chartNumber) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if((chartNumber >= CHART_LOWER_LIMIT) && (chartNumber<= CHART_UPPER_LIMIT)) {
            this.chartNumber = chartNumber;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Chart not in bounds");
        }
    }

}
```

Following is the my test case code.

```
package testartist;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import song.Artist;

class TestArtist {
    
    String name,nameInvalid, genre,genreInvalid, artistName, artistNameInvalid;
    int chartNumber, chartNumberInvalid;
    double length, lengthInvalid;
    

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        
        name = "Beautiful day";
        nameInvalid = "";
        genre = "Country";
        genreInvalid = "";
        artistName = "Bono";
        artistNameInvalid = "";
        chartNumber = 3;
        chartNumberInvalid = 15;
        length = 2.56;
        lengthInvalid = 5.45;
    }

    @Test
    void testDefaultConstructor() {
        
        Artist song = new Artist();
        
        
    }

    @Test
    void testConstructorWithArgs() {
        
        Artist artist = new Artist(name, genre, length, chartNumber, artistName);
        
        assertEquals(name, artist.getName() );
        assertEquals(genre, artist.getGenre() );
        assertEquals(length, artist.getLength() );
        assertEquals(chartNumber, artist.getChartNumber());
        assertEquals(artistName, artist.getArtistName());
    }
    
    @Test
    void testInvalidConstructorWithArgs() {
        
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            Artist artist = new Artist(name, genre, length, chartNumber, artistNameInvalid);
            }); 
        
    }

    
    

@Test
    void testSetGetArtistName() {
    
    Artist a = new Artist();
    a.setArtistName(artistName);
    assertEquals(artistName, a.getArtistName());
    }

    @Test
    void testSetGetName() {
    Artist a = new Artist();
    a.setName(name);
    assertEquals(name, a.getName());
    }

    @Test
    void testSetGetGenre() {
        Artist a = new Artist();
        a.setGenre(genre);
        assertEquals(genre, a.getGenre());
    }

    @Test
    void testSetGetLength() {
        Artist a = new Artist();
        a.setLength(length);
        assertEquals(length, a.getLength());
        
    }

    @Test
    void testSetGetChartNumber() {
        Artist a = new Artist();
        a.setChartNumber(chartNumber);
        assertEquals(chartNumber, a.getChartNumber());
    }

}
```

** Artist code

package song;

public class Artist extends song {

```
private static final int ARTIST_NAME_LOWER_LIMIT = 1;

private String artistName;

public Artist() {
    
}

public Artist(String name, String genre, double length, int chartNumber, String artistName) {
    super(name, genre, length, chartNumber);
    this.artistName = artistName;
}

/**
 * @return the artistName
 */
public String getArtistName() {
    return artistName;
}

/**
 * @param artistName the artistName to set
 */
public void setArtistName(String artistName) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if( artistName.length()>= ARTIST_NAME_LOWER_LIMIT) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name too short");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `Artist` class? Does its constructor throw an IllegalArgumentException? Do any of the methods called inside the constructor throw an IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: @byxor Yeah so my Artist class extends my Song class and also contains an IllegalArguementException for set name

Comment: Please add the `Artist` code to your question. My crystal ball isn't working today, so I can't tell you why the code in that class doesn't throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. I'm guessing your problem is that you throw the `IllegalArgumentException` in a `setName` method, but the constructor doesn't use this method and does `this.name = name` instead.

Comment: You genius! Didn't even realise that mistake. Thank you so much, its finally working 

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly implemented the validation inside the `setArtistName` method.

```
/**
 * @param artistName the artistName to set
 */
public void setArtistName(String artistName) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if( artistName.length()>= ARTIST_NAME_LOWER_LIMIT) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name too short");
    }
}
```

But your constructor doesn't use this method, therefore it skips the validation.

```
public Artist(String name, String genre, double length, int chartNumber, String artistName) {
    super(name, genre, length, chartNumber);
    this.artistName = artistName;
}
```

You need to call your setter method instead.

```
public Artist(String name, String genre, double length, int chartNumber, String artistName) {
    super(name, genre, length, chartNumber);
    this.setArtistName(artistName); // or just setArtistName(artistName);
}
```